# Scala filter and print a class

Tags: scala, class, object

So I have defined here a class:

```
class CsvEntry(val organisation: String, val yearAndQuartal : String, val medKF:Int, val trueOrFalse: Int, val name: String, val money:String){
  override def toString = s"$organisation, $yearAndQuartal, $medKF, $trueOrFalse, $name, $money"
}
```

Lets assume the value of "medKF" is wheter 2,4 or 31.
How can I filter all CsvEntries to only give me an output for these where the "medKF" is 2? (with foreach println)?

Comment: `entries filter(_.medKF == 2) foreach println` ?

Comment: Thank you!
I have another question:
Lets assume in my variable "medKF" are numbers stored like "55,43"
and I want to count them together, so of every line I want to take the value of "medKF" and add it to a value whats called lets say "sum"?

Comment: its an `Int`, so how can you store `"55,43"` ?

Comment: oh I apologize I meant the variable called "money" there are values like this.
now I want only to sum up these values in the variable "money" of every line where my medKF says 2 (already got this now)!

Comment: split the string by comma, map them to int and call sum on the array.

Comment: I think @ArmaGeddon wants  `val sum = filteredEntries.map(_.medKF).map(_.replaceAll(",", ".").toDouble).sum`

Comment: @PeterNeyens No. Lets say this is my CsvEntry:
Miller,2014Q1,2,1,MillerIncorporation,556,32

now I want all lines where the "medKF" equals 2...
from these lines where the medKF is 2 I now want the last number like here in this example "556,32" and sum them all up to one total sum!

Comment: @ArmaGeddon I accidentally wrote `_.medKF` instead of `_.money`. Try `val sum = filteredEntries.map(_.money).map(_.replaceAll(",", ".").toDouble).sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating two random entries:

```
val a = new CsvEntry("s", "11", 12, 0, "asdasd", "1")
val b = new CsvEntry("s", "11", 2, 0, "asdasd", "234,123.23")
```

Then filter:

```
List(a,b).withFilter(_.medKF == 2).foreach(println)
```

To sum those entries:

```
List(a,b).map(_.medKF).sum
```

To add the money:

```
 def moneyToCent(money: String): Long = (money.replace(",","").toDouble*100).toLong
 List(a,b).withFilter(_.medKF == 2).map(x => moneyToCent(x.money)).sum
```